# How to get the value only from an input box that contains value out of multiple input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the value from an input box that contains value. Only one of them contains some value out of 3 and remaining 2 are empty:

The code mentioned below doesn't seems to work:

```
var a = $('input').eq(0).val();

if (a == undefined) {
 a = $('input').eq(1).val();
 //if still undefined try the next input box
 if (a == undefined) {
   a = $('input').eq(2).val();  
 }
}
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to find the `input` that has a value entered you can use `filter()` instead of repeatedly checking them. Try this:

```js
var $field = $('input').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val().trim() != '';
});

console.log($field.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" value="foo" />
<input type="text" value="" />
```

Note that the above assumes that only one field will ever have a value. If there will be multiple, then you'll need to loop over the resulting collection in `$field`.

Comment: More convenient way of getting the OP output. +1